# how to write a test case for msg.sender==0?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, testing

In my contract I am use the below mapping.
    mapping(address => uint)Drivers
In the function

```
    function registerDriver(uint _perkm) public payable returns(string memory) {
           require(Drivers[msg.sender] == 0,"You are already registered as 
    Driver.");
            driverCount++;
            driverList.push(Driver({
                driverID : driverCount,
            driverAddr : msg.sender,
            rideID : 0,
            perkm : _perkm,
            currentStatus : available,
            bids: 0

        }));
        Drivers[msg.sender] = driverCount;
        return "You are registered as Driver.";
    }
```

Can someone help me write test case for the above function? i.e - test case for my require statement. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test case for your `require` statement should be for `Drivers[msg.sender] == 0`, not for `msg.sender == 0` as specified in the title of your question (which by the way is impossible, since you'll need the private key of address 0 in order to generate such transaction).

That said, the test case above is really simple - just call the function twice using the same account.

Side note: the return-value of this function looks completely redundant; I'd advise you to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So, I actually dont know how to write the test case for this condition.. I can test it by clicking the funciton twice in Remix. how do I write a unit test case say for require condition? Am a newbie here!

Comment: @Shalu: You can start [here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you, I have no pointers for testing msg.sender part only.. there arent any examples for this msg.sender test is it?

Comment: @Shalu: Have you read my answer??? There's nothing to test with a specific `msg.sender` here. Just call the function twice with the same account. Make sure that it completes successfully the first time, and reverts (throws an exception) the second time.

Comment: thank you very much for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

```
require(Driver[msg.sender] == address(0));
```